# PowerShell reports invalid error line number when mandatory parameter is present

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I've noticed that my PowerShell script started reporting invalid line numbers in case of script failure, which greatly complicates error troubleshooting. I've nailed the problem to a following sample script:

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]$foo
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
"Line 5"
Systax Error here
"Line 7"
```

Without either 'Mandatory' keyword or without '$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"' error line number is properly reported:

```
Systax : The term 'Systax' is not recognized ...
At C:\scripts\1.ps1:6 char:1
```

But if you run provided sample script, you get this error in PowerShell console:

```
C:\scripts\1.ps1 : The term 'Systax' is not recognized ...
At line:1 char:1
```

and no line number at all when running sample script in PowerShell ISE editor. **In console error line number is always reported as line:1.** For large scripts not knowing which line contains error is a real issue.

Described behavior looks like a bug in PowerShell. Does anybody knows a workaround that allows get proper error line numbers while preserving Mandatory parameters and '$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"'? PowerShell version that I'm using is 5.1.

Comment: Note that `Systax Error here` is not a syntax error. With syntax error it does not matter what else you have in the script, because not a single line from it will be executed.

Comment: PetSerAl, you are right. Bad sample from me. But I think you got a point of the sample.

Comment: You can always use `ScriptStackTrace` property of `ErrorRecord` to inspect full call stack at the point when error happens.

Comment: The only solution I've found so far - don't use [Parameter] attributes.